# problem when converting R file to R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

when I was trying to convert an R file to R markdown file through compile report function in Rstudio. I encountered this error message which I don't understand why.

```
processing file: airline_customerSatisfaction.spin.Rmd
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1

Quitting from lines 3-346 (airline_customerSatisfaction.spin.Rmd) 
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url
In addition: Warning message:
In do_once((if (is_R_CMD_check()) stop else warning)("The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please ",  :
  The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please consider using base::isFALSE(x) or identical(x, FALSE) instead.
Execution halted
```

can someone explain to me why does this happened? Thanks!

Comment: it is not really clear what's going on if you don't provide a reproducible example. It appears, however, that you have a call to "install.packages" that is causing trouble...  you can probably remove it from the Rmd file, as you probably have already installed that package

Comment: I suspect the [tag:rstudio] tag is not correct here, can you confirm that this works correctly in R (not within RStudio) and breaks only when compiled in the IDE? The tag recommendation system is imperfect, please check them when asking your questions, and be mindful of spamming tags that are incorrect.

Comment: You seem to have `install.packages()` in your Rmd file. Remove it.

Comment: @Phil why this is a problem? I am new to RMD, do you mind elaborate a little bit?

Comment: First of all, you only need to install packages once, so it's redundant and a timewaster to re-install it every time you knit the document. Furthermore, knitting takes place in a fresh environment devoid of whatever global settings you normally use to install packages, such as what CRAN mirror is being used. Since it is not specified in the file, you are running into an error where R doesn't know where to install the packages from.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the knitr package to the latest version (1.42) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had to update knitr and rmarkdown. It happened because of this: https://yihui.org/en/2023/02/xfun-isfalse/